# Pass Jquery Array to MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have been trying all of the examples given on SO for passing an array generated by jQuery to PHP to store in a MySql DB but all I get on the PHP side is "Array".

I am writing code for a Bingo game.  My jquery generates and array called "drawArray" which should be stored in my database. Example:

```
 ["N37", "G72", "O47", "I43", "N26", "G65", "I62", "N14", "B69", "G67", "I63", "G09", "G01", "G52", "N57", "B42", "N21", "I54", "N21", "N13", "N10", "N01", "N71", "I21", "O01", "G72", "O27", "G32", "O31", "B19", "O34", "I69", "O49", "O29", "G52", "O26", "I34", "I66", "I68", "I60"]
```

I have tried ajax, jquery.post and either way I either get noting on the PHP side or I only get "Array"

Here is my jQuery:

```
 $("#draw").click(function() {
        drawNumbers();
        console.log(drawArray);

        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/dealerpicks.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'drawArray[]' : drawArray},
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        });



    });
```

And on my PHP side:

```
    //POST Data
$DealerNums = $_POST['drawArray'];

echo $DealerNums . "<br><br>";

$sql="INSERT INTO drawings (dealerPicks)
                VALUES
                ('$DealerNums')";

                if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
                    {
                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                    }
                echo "1 record added";
                mysqli_close($conn)
  ?>
```

So of course I need to store all of those dealer numbers into the DB for later use when drawing out the Bingo Card. I figured I would store it and all of the drawings into an array in the DB to be referenced later in my PHP.

Why am I only getting "Array" for a value?

Comment: To print an `array` use `print_r($DealerNums);`. I also will suggest to use `json_encode` of array while storing in DB or `serialize`

Comment: you need to turn that array into JSON. Try it with `JSON.stringify(drawArray)`

Answer (score 0):

`$DealerNums` is an array. You are using it as a string. Something like this should solve your problem, I am also adding a couple of safety checks:

```
$DealerNums = $_POST['DealerNums'];

if (!is_array($DealerNums))
{
  // handle error 
}

//escape_string to avoid SQL injection
$DealerStr = $conn->escape_string(join(',', $DealerNums));

$sql="INSERT INTO drawings (dealerPicks)
                VALUES
                ('$DealerStr')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for recommending JSO Stringify.

My updated code is as follows:

```
 $("#draw").click(function() {
        drawNumbers();
        console.log(drawArray);
        var jsonDrawArray = JSON.stringify(drawArray);

        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/dealerpicks.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {data:jsonDrawArray},
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
        });
```

and my PHP:

```
 //POST Data
$DealerNums = $_POST['data'];

echo $DealerNums . "<br><br>";

$sql="INSERT INTO drawings (dealerPicks)
                VALUES
                ('$DealerNums')";

                if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
                    {
                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                    }
                echo "1 record added";
                mysqli_close($conn)
  ?>
```

Then for those of you following, I am using the Array later on in my PHP page like this:

```
 <?php
                $query = "SELECT dealerPicks FROM drawings WHERE drawID = '14'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                if($result === FALSE) { 
                    die(mysqli_error());
                }

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    $dealer = json_decode($row['dealerPicks']);

                    foreach ($dealer as $key => $value) {

                        $letter = substr($value, -3, 1);
                        $number = substr($value, -2, 2);
                        echo '<div class="dealernum"><span class="alphabet">'.$letter.'</span>'.$number.'</div>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an answer. Im glad I was able to help. Let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're sending is not in correct format. Try it like this:

```
function drawNumbers() {
    return ["N37", "G72", "O47", "I43", "N26", "G65", "I62", "N14", "B69", "G67", "I63", "G09", "G01", "G52", "N57", "B42", "N21", "I54", "N21", "N13", "N10", "N01", "N71", "I21", "O01", "G72", "O27", "G32", "O31", "B19", "O34", "I69", "O49", "O29", "G52", "O26", "I34", "I66", "I68", "I60"];

}
$("#draw").click(function () {
    var drawArray = drawNumbers();
    $.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {drawArray: JSON.stringify(drawArray)},
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```